# Google Firebase get an email for new user signup

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a mobile app using Google Flutter and Google Firebase, is there a way to get an email notification for each new user that is created using Firebase auth which is sent from Firebase and not the application.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that will do this automatically for you.  You could use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to write an [auth trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) that implements sending mail when a new user account is created.  This will require a fair amount of work on your part to put together.  There are many libraries and services you can use to send the email, so be sure to do some research to figure out which ones might work best for you.

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty easy at the end, I just added the [Google Firebase Trigger Email extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) and wrote a simple function